# how to stop anything slider from adding hash tags to the URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, anythingslider

anything slider is adding hash tags like `#&panel1-1` at the end of the url.

I tried `hashtags:false` but it does not work.

Is there any other way to stop  it from generating those hashtags?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try changing it to `hashTags:false` .

Notice the capital T in tag.

Comment: Thank You Playmaker !! damn T took 30 min from my life.

Comment: Fortunately didn't take much off mine as I thought of googling it instead of R&D'ing myself :D

Answer (score 0):

Oh hey, if you're using AnythingSlide in WordPress there is actually an option under Settings > Navigation Settings > Display Hashtags that gets rid of it without needing to touch the files.