# Removing the extra part attached to the URL

Tags: html, anythingslider

I am updating a website, and I used a plugin and it seems now the url has additional part: `"#&panel1-1"`. Is there a way to remove this hash part?

The url of my website is:

```
http://www.auburn.edu/student_info/nsa/index.html#&panel1-1
```

I want to change that url to

```
http://www.auburn.edu/student_info/nsa/index.html
```

Thank you so much.

Comment: can u just change the name of that page on the server?

Comment: "Stop using the plugin". (Seriously, we don't know what the plugin is, what it does, or why it twiddles with the fragment identifier, so we can't tell you what you can do about it. That said, it smells of the [hashbang problem](http://isolani.co.uk/blog/javascript/BreakingTheWebWithHashBangs) so the best solution is probably going to involve rewriting large amounts of the plugin).

Comment: @imulsion — Since the fragment identifier is never sent to the server, that seems unlikely.

Comment: Not with just HTML. You are gonna need `Javascript` or a `.htaccess` rewrite.

Comment: Ummm, just change the URL to `http://www.auburn.edu/student_info/nsa/index.html`?

Comment: @jimjimmy1995 — Presumably the plugin is JavaScript that is adding the fragment identifier in the first place. Since fragment identifiers are never sent to the server, no amount of Apache configuration is going to get rid of it.

Comment: @ imulsion : Thank you for your reply. In the server the name is index.html but when it is displayed on browser, then hash part is automatically generated.

Comment: Where is this URL?  What do you mean "change the URL"? How/when does the `#&panel1-1` get added?  What does this "plugin" do?  Why are you using it? Why does it matter if `#&panel1-1` is there or not?  Can you just not use the "plugin"?

Comment: @ Rocket Hazmat : The plugin is the slideshow plugin. I don't know how that #&panel1-1 get added. Thats what I am trying to figure out. By changing the url I mean while loading on the browser, I want to get rid of that hash part.

Comment: @Jdbaba: It's called a [URL fragment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier), and it's added by the plugin to identify the image in the slideshow you are currently on.  So, if you click "refresh", or send someone a link with it there, it can load that image.  Why do you want to remove it?

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11020854/how-to-stop-anything-slider-from-adding-hash-tags-to-the-url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [demo page](http://css-tricks.com/examples/AnythingSlider/) for the plugin you can get rid of the hash in the URL by initializing it with:

```
$('#slider').anythingSlider({{hashTags: false});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I am sorry. I didn't realize it was a duplicate. Will keep in mind next time.